# octomap_frame in Moveit

Tags: moveit, husky, octomap, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to map an area with a 3D Lidar and Husky. I hope to build an Octomap of the area and use Moveit to plan movements of the UR5 to prevent collisions.

I am following the [Husky UR5 Demo](http://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/husky/HuskyManip.html) and [Moveit Perception Tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/src/doc/perception_configuration.html).

I have added a Velodyne VLP-16 (velodyne_simulator from DataspeedInc) to the Husky Model in /opt/ros/indigo/share/husky_description/urdf/husky.urdf.xacro.

I notice that the octomap is displayed in rviz. However, when the Husky is moved, I see a duplicate of obstacles in the octomap (i.e. both the previous and current location). I believe I have set the octomap_frame = "odom".

So I tried octomap_server (roslaunch octomap_server octomap_mapping.launch) and displayed it in rviz (occupied_cells_vis_array). I have set frame_id  = "odom" as well. This time, the octomap seems to update and the obstacles are fixed in place.

As such, I wonder if Moveit supports this, and if so, have I configured it incorrectly?

Edit: I have done some digging through the source code "occupancy_map_monitor.cpp" and found that the param octomap_frame is not used. It seems that map_frame_ had previously been set (I believe to /base_link). As I get this msg when launching moveit - Listening to '/velodyne_points' using message filter with target frame '/base_link'

Is there a way to make moveit use octomap_frame?

Thanks in advanced.

I am running on the following:

14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP

ROS Indigo

rviz version 1.11.19

Gazebo version 2.2.3

Moveit version 0.7.13-Alpha

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306955/octomap_frame-in-moveit/) by [jacoblim20](https://answers.ros.org/users/38216/jacoblim20/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-10-28

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-29**:
This could be an issue of the MoveIt octomap updater plugin: it only deletes voxels if it can raytrace through them to another occupied voxel that is "behind" the closer one (from the perspective of the sensor).

**Comment by [jacoblim20](https://answers.ros.org/users/38216/jacoblim20/) on 2018-10-29**:
Thanks gvdhoorn.

I looked at pointcloud_octomap_updater.cpp and noticed that when i run
`roslaunch husky_ur5_moveit_config husky_ur5_planning_execution.launch sim:=true`

i get this msg
Listening to '/velodyne_points' using message filter with target frame '/base_link'
even if i set "odom"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For your reference: https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/1188

---

UPDATE by @130s: I haven't verified. I don't even know if the problem persists in newer code base. Just copy-pasting the workaround the author from [moveit#1188](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/1188#issuecomment-467675156) verified:

> I now understand that the planningscene frame is set to the root link in the URDF/SRDF by default. In my case, this caused the octomap to always update in the frame of my mobile robot. The solution was to add a virtual joint in my SRDF that connects the fixed frame (map) to the root link on my robot.

---

Originally posted by [sdfryc](https://answers.ros.org/users/40154/sdfryc/) with karma: 18 on 2019-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0